# Write exponents as superscripts

Tags: r, numeric, dt, exponent, superscript

consider the following list of numbers in R

```
list_num<-c(1,10, 100, NA, 0.1)
```

Can this be printed in this format [image]

The printing should be as if they are numbers so that we can sort the same. I request someone to help a bit. I am unable to find a solution

Comment: note : between 10 raised to 2 and NA there is a comma.

Comment: Just to clarify: you want this to be displayed inside a “datatables” instance (via the R ‘DT’ package)? Or something else?

Comment: inside a datatable

Comment: That’s my point: what do you mean by “datatable”? The word isn’t a widely recognised term in the context of R (“datatables” (plural) is, and so is ‘data.table’ (a package). Please clarify how exactly you’re using this, it matters for the answer.

Comment: We have a renderdatatable option in R shiny. IT basically renders a dataframe as a datatable with filters. It should work interchangeably I belive as most functions work across both

Comment: OK, so what you’re talking about is datatable**s**. That’s the name of the JavaScript package.